# How can I actually grab the data out of a running stream/websocket within a function?

Tags: python

I am quite confused how to handle websockets/streams data within a function in Python.

I have a Python script that triggers a [ws/stream](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/master/alpaca_trade_api/stream.py) which runs 24/7:

```
async def quote_callback(q):
    print('quote', q)
    return q

# Initiate Class Instance
stream = Stream(public_key,
                secret_key,
                base_url=base_url,
                data_feed='sip')

# Subscribing to all relevant symbols
for symbol in traded_symbols:
    stream.subscribe_quotes(quote_callback, symbol)

# run stream
stream.run()
```

This returns an infinite stream of quotes for all symbols in `traded_symbols`:

```
quote Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'N',
    'ask_price': 79.0,
    'ask_size': 5,
    'bid_exchange': 'U',
    'bid_price': 78.99,
    'bid_size': 3,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'MRK',
    'tape': 'A',
    'timestamp': 1641496334124695884})
quote Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'H',
    'ask_price': 334.64,
    'ask_size': 1,
    'bid_exchange': 'A',
    'bid_price': 334.48,
    'bid_size': 1,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'FB',
    'tape': 'C',
    'timestamp': 1641496334125929728})

... etc.
```

Now I have a function within this script where I want to grab the (last) next value out of the stream for any given symbol like so:

```
def get_quote(symbol):
    ask_price = # stream to catch the (last) occurring ask_price of symbol
    return ask_price

get_quote("FB")
# should return --> 334.64
```

How to accomplish this?

It seems that all of the code after `stream.run` isn't executed when triggered via `main.py` while loop?

```
# trader.py

# Stream logic
quotes = {}

async def quote_callback(q):
    quotes[q.symbol] = q
    print(q)
    return q

# Initiate Class Instance
stream = Stream(public_key,
                secret_key,
                base_url=base_url,
                data_feed='sip')  # <- replace to SIP if you have PRO subscription

# Subscribing to all symbols
for symbol in traded_symbols:
    stream.subscribe_quotes(quote_callback, symbol)

# run stream
stream.run()

def run_rufus():
    ...
    stream_price = quotes[symbol].ask_price
```

```
# main.py
from trader import run_rufus

while True:
    run_rufus()
```

When I remove all of the stream part `run_rufus()` is continuously executed. I guess there is some bug with my code structure.

**Update**

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from alpaca_trade_api.stream import Stream

# Grab required env variables
secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
public_key = os.environ['PUB_KEY']
base_url = os.environ['APCA_API_BASE_URL']

traded_symbols = [
    "ADBE", # Adobe
    "ABNB", # Airbnb
    "AMZN", # Amazon
    "FB"
]

quotes = {}

async def quote_callback(q):
    quotes[q.symbol] = q
    print(q)
    print(F'-----------------------------')
    print(F'Quotes: {quotes}')
    return q

# Initiate Class Instance
stream = Stream(public_key,
                secret_key,
                base_url=base_url,
                data_feed="sip")

# Subscribing to all relevant symbols
for symbol in traded_symbols:
    stream.subscribe_quotes(quote_callback, symbol)

# run stream
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=stream.run)
p.start()

def get_quote(symbol):
    if symbol in quotes: # if the dictionary quotes has a key with the value of symbol
        return quotes[symbol].ask_price
    return -1 # a return value of -1 indicates that there was no quote with the given symbol received yet

price = get_quote("FB")
while price == -1:
    price = get_quote("FB")
print(price)
```

returns

```
Quotes: {'ABNB': Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'M',
    'ask_price': 156.7,
    'ask_size': 1,
    'bid_exchange': 'Q',
    'bid_price': 156.57,
    'bid_size': 2,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'ABNB',
    'tape': 'C',
    'timestamp': 1641840163168672614}), 'ADBE': Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'P',
    'ask_price': 517.0,
    'ask_size': 2,
    'bid_exchange': 'P',
    'bid_price': 516.79,
    'bid_size': 1,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'ADBE',
    'tape': 'C',
    'timestamp': 1641840163466840647}), 'FB': Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'Q',
    'ask_price': 323.97,
    'ask_size': 3,
    'bid_exchange': 'V',
    'bid_price': 323.88,
    'bid_size': 3,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'FB',
    'tape': 'C',
    'timestamp': 1641840160572326189}), 'AMZN': Quote({   'ask_exchange': 'M',
    'ask_price': 3178.2,
    'ask_size': 2,
    'bid_exchange': 'M',
    'bid_price': 3175.81,
    'bid_size': 2,
    'conditions': ['R'],
    'symbol': 'AMZN',
    'tape': 'C',
    'timestamp': 1641840162908516864})
}
```

Comment: This is not very clear, you should just look at the value for the key you want in your dictionary

Comment: But how can I access the dicts returned by the stream 24/7?

Comment: First you need to tell us where you got this Stream class from. Is it in the standard library ? A 3rd party library ? Self-written ?

Comment: @Programmer oh yes sry. 3rd party - it is a community based SDK for alpaca.markets. However, the docu is insufficient for average Joe's like me :(

Comment: Now, if you tell me where I can find that library I could take a quick look at the source code and see if I can find a solution for your problem ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can directly access the dictionary fields as members of the `Quote` objects - i.e. you can just do `q.ask_price` to get the price from the received `Quote`s.

In your `quote_callback` function you get every `Quote` object as an argument. So, if you always only want to access the last received `Quote` object which has `symbol` = `"HB"`, you could define a global dictionary named e.g. `quotes` which will contain one key == symbol and value == last `Quote` with that symbol per symbol type.

Now, in `get_quote` you can use a simple dictionary lookup for the desired key in the `quotes` dictionary. In the end, you need to repeatedly call `get_quote` until a quote object with the desired symbol value is received. The whole code could look like this:

```py
import multiprocessing

quotes = {}

async def quote_callback(q):
    quotes[q.symbol] = q
    return q

# Initiate Class Instance
stream = Stream(public_key,
                secret_key,
                base_url=base_url,
                data_feed="sip")

# Subscribing to all relevant symbols
for symbol in traded_symbols:
    stream.subscribe_quotes(quote_callback, symbol)

# run stream
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=stream.run)
p.start()

def get_quote(symbol):
    if symbol in quotes.keys():
        return quotes[symbol].ask_price
    print(quotes)
    return -1

price = get_quote("FB")
while price == -1:
    price = get_quote("FB")
print(price)
```

If there are any errors, please add them to your question, then I can take a look.

Comment: thanks! I think I'm pretty close, but somehow my script doesn't execute the function. I trigger one script via the main.py on a cloud hosted service (replit.com). If I remove the stream part it fires the function 24/7 though.

Comment: @Jonas well, I thought `stream.run` were non-blocking since it's run through `asyncio`, but that doesn't seem to be the case … can you try the new code please ?

Comment: tested it and it seems it doesn't call `get_quote` when running my main.py file.. hmh. `Stream.run` however is triggered and running

Comment: @Jonas okay, sorry, but I've run out of ideas now …

Comment: it is working, i had a typo in my code :) thanks mate!

Comment: ah false alarm... it is close to work I think. I used your example 1:1 but it never `print(price)`. I think the issue is that the dictionary `quotes` isn't populated. Once I print it it is always empty.

Comment: @Jonas at least we're gettting somewhere - I have added two print statements, please rerun the code and post the output (you'd want to kill it after it printed 10 quotes though)

Comment: added :) The dict is now populated as far as I see it. I think the issue is within `if symbol in quotes` which doesn't return `True`

Comment: tried it back and forth, `if symbol in quotes` doesn't value to `True`, even though `FB` is a symbol in quotes. I don't get it

Comment: @Jonas that's weird … please try the new code and look if it really prints an FB symbol in quotes. If it doesn't work now, I'm out of ideas …